# Calendar object in Java, returns wrong time?

Tags: java, string, time, calendar

So I've been working on a simple little method which would return a `String` as `Calendar` object.

Here's what I have:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

try {
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(this.getCreated_at()));
}
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return cal;
```

Now assuming that the `String` obtained from `this.getCreated_at())` is always in the desired format, this should, theoretically, work perfectly.

There's only one little hiccup.

Assume that `this.getCreated_at())` returns `Mon Feb 10 18:52:54 +0000 2014`. Shouldn't be a problem right? The format is correct, and everything.

However when I have my main method do as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");

System.out.println(sdf.format(... ... ....stringToCalendar().getTime()));
```

It gives me the following output:

```
ma feb 10 19:52:54 +0100 2014
```

My problem, as you may have noticed, is that firstly, the time is wrong. It's added an hour.

Secondly, it's translated the text fields `Mon` and `Feb` into `ma` and `feb` which are translations to Norwegian, the place from where I'm coding now.

I need the time returned to me as a `Calendar` object, in the exact manner which it was obtained from the `this.getCreated_at())`-string.

What am I doing wrong?

Can anyone help me out?

I'm from Norway, by the way. That's +01:00 Standard Offset.

Comment: The SimpleDateFormat you're using to display the value is in the default (Norwegian) locale and time zone, not in English. So it displays the date in Norwegian, using the Norwegian time zone.

Comment: @PavelHoral Updated. That was just a typo from me being a little too hasty. Pardons.

Comment: Why do you think it's displaying the wrong time?  `19:52:24 +01:00` looks perfectly correct to me - it's the same as `18:52:24 +00:00`, but displayed for YOUR timezone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My problem, as you may have noticed, is that firstly, the time is wrong. It's added an hour.

No it hasn't. Not really. It's displaying the exact same time, but in your local time zone. Unfortunately you can't easily determine the original time zone, because `DateFormat.parse` returns a `Date`, which doesn't contain any time zone information. (In this case you don't really know the full time zone anyway - you just know the UTC offset, which isn't quite the same thing.)

EDIT: As noted in Joni's answer, it appears that `DateFormat.parse` *does* retain the original information in the format's calendar; you wouldn't want the time zone, but you could use the offset stored in the `Calendar` object. Personally this seems to me to be an implementation detail which I wouldn't want to rely on (especially as you end up with an offset which isn't necessarily supported by the time zone in the same calendar object!) but you *could* mangle it if you really wanted.

> Secondly, it's translated the text fields Mon and Feb into ma and feb which are translations to Norwegian, the place from where I'm coding now.

That's because your `SimpleDateFormat` is using your default locale.

You can fix this part very easily:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy",
    Locale.ENGLISH);
```

If you *know* what time zone you want to use, you can specify that on the `SimpleDateFormat` as well. Otherwise, you're going to have a slightly harder time.

I would recommend that instead, you start using [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time). That way you can parse the value as a `DateTime`, which "knows" which time zone it's in - so you can reformat it however you want, preserving the relevant time zone information.

Sample Joda Time code:

```
import java.util.*;
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat
            .forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")
            .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

        String input = "Mon Feb 10 18:52:54 +0000 2014";

        DateTime value = format.parseDateTime(input);
        System.out.println(format.print(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is most helpful, and I do think Joda Time looks appealing. Could you perhaps show me, in your answer, how I would go about using it in my method? If I sound picky, it is not my intent. Your answer is really useful!

Comment: @ViRALiC: See my edit... I was just working up the example :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Could I then convert the `DateTime` object value, to a `Calendar` object, which would then be returned? Or would my problem go with it? I hate to burden you more, but my method really does need to return a `Calendar` object.

Comment: @ViRALiC: You *could* convert it to a `Calendar` (there's even a `toCalendar` method), but you'd be much better off converting *everything* to use Joda Time if you possibly can.

Comment: I'd ask you to show me how to convert it to a `Calendar` object, if only to sate my curiosity. But you have already helped me a lot, so even if you should chose not to demonstrate, your answer is absolutely accepted!

Answer (score -1):

You can get the `Calendar` instance from the date format:

```
sdf.parse(this.getCreated_at());
Calendar parsed = sdf.getCalendar();
```

This instance has the fields set to what was parsed: UTC timezone, time 18:52:54, etc...

Unfortunately there appears to be no way to format the values held by `Calendar` using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: No it doesn't. Parsing doesn't change the calendar in the format. (I've just tested this.)

Comment: Sure it does Jon, [that's how `SimpleDateFormat` works](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java#SimpleDateFormat.parse%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.text.ParsePosition%29). I'd like to see how you checked it, I know you're not going to get something like this wrong.

Comment: I apologise - it does change *some* of the fields in the calendar. It does *not* change the time zone though. Try parsing a value with "+0800" in, printing out the time zone in the calendar before and after - you'll see it doesn't change. (At least, mine still says "Europe/London" afterwards, and an offset of 8 hours is certainly *not* valid for Europe/London.) And if you just format the value you parsed using the same formatter, it *won't* (necessarily) give you back the same result - precisely because parsing doesn't change the time zone.

Comment: You could get the offset using `calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)` but this still feels like an implementation detail to me - can you point at any *documentation* which states that the calendar is populated in this way?

Comment: "This parsing operation uses the calendar to produce a Date. As a result, the calendar's date-time fields and the TimeZone value may have been overwritten, depending on subclass implementations. Any TimeZone value that has previously been set by a call to setTimeZone may need to be restored for further operations." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29  (Knew it had to be there somewhere..)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But "may have been overwritten" doesn't sound like something I'd want to *depend* on though... It would be possible to write an implementation which *didn't* change the state of the calendar. (Indeed, I'd suggest that would be preferable - it's very annoying that DateFormat implementations aren't thread-safe...)

Comment: Oh there's more in the docs for `SimpleDateFormat`: *The TimeZone value may be overwritten, depending on the given pattern and the time zone value in text.* http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29 It doesn't specify *in what way* it depends on the pattern and text being parsed though

Comment: Right. Again, that's not something I'd want to depend on - and in this particular case, it *doesn't* change the time zone on the implementation I'm using, for example.

Comment: Which  implementation is that, Jon? In my experience SDF has always populated the Calendar fully, but I haven't tested all JDKs

Comment: It's the Oracle JDK 7 on Windows. But try it yourself - print the calendar's time zone before and after parsing the format in question but with an offset of (say) +0800. On my machine, the time zone itself stays as Europe/London.

Comment: Ah that is true: the `TimeZone` stays the same, but the `ZONE_OFFSET` is updated, which is good enough (or better, even). Sadly the spec does not give any guarantees about `ZONE_OFFSET`, so it's underspecified to be actually reliable.